# ng-if does not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if

In my project I am facing an issue that ng-if is not working. I want to remove/add text field when value of $scope.edit changes.

I have created a simplest of example in the jsfiddle below.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="edit" ng-init="edit = true">
    <div ng-bind="edit"></div>
    <div ng-if="edit">
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" size="30" placeholder="New Name" />
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Johny";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/32009/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Fiddle may not work because you are using **Angular 1.0.1** [which has some issue in `ng-if`](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/fecvqsw5/).

### Solution 1

If you are really using this version, you can replace `ng-if` by `ng-show` (which will create hidden elements in the DOM).

```
<div ng-show="edit">
```

[Demo on JSFiddle using ng-show](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/fecvqsw5/)

### Solution 2

Anyway, the best solution would be to use **Angular 1.2+** which fixes `ng-if` bugs in `ng-repeat`. As you can see in the following snippet, I didn't change your code, and it works.

[Demo on JSFiddle using ng-if](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/pnnzb5sm/)

Comment: Can you please fix the fiddle to angular 1.2+. I don't know how.

Comment: @Ashwin I've updated my question, here is your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/pnnzb5sm/

Answer (score 1):

**Some observations :**

- Seems that your angular version is old. hence, `ng-if` is not working.
- If you want to use only existing angular version then you can use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`.

**Demo with ng-if :**

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Johny";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="edit" ng-init="edit = true">
    <div ng-bind="edit"></div>
    <div ng-if="edit">
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" size="30" placeholder="New Name" />
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**Demo with ng-show :**

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Johny";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="edit" ng-init="edit = true">
    <div ng-bind="edit"></div>
    <div ng-show="edit">
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" size="30" placeholder="New Name" />
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-show instead

```
<div ng-show=edit>
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" size="30" placeholder="New Name" />
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tej6zakn/)**

Update the angular version with 1.2 or above with ng-if

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.name = "Johny";
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="edit" ng-init="edit = true">
    <div ng-bind="edit"></div>
    <div ng-show=edit>
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" size="30" placeholder="New Name" />
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot hide/show in my project. I need to add or remove completely.

Comment: even if you use ng-if it does the same

Comment: @Ashwin check the demo